# How to remove one line from a file using Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to remove one line from a text file. Instead, what I have wipes out the entire file. Can someone point out the error?

```
removeReservation("john");

sub removeTime() {
    my $name = shift;

    open( FILE, "<times.txt" );
    @LINES = <FILE>;
    close(FILE);
    open( FILE, ">times.txt" );
    foreach $LINE (@LINES) {
        print NEWLIST $LINE unless ( $LINE =~ m/$name/ );
    }
    close(FILE);
    print("Reservation successfully removed.<br/>");
}
```

Sample times.txt file:

```
04/15/2012&08:00:00&bob
04/15/2012&08:00:00&john
```

Comment: @geekosaur I'm not getting anything from warnings..

Comment: Then your output is going somewhere other than where it should be.  Check where you're writing it.

Comment: @geekosaur, the real program probably uses `NEWLIST` somewhere else, which means you don't get the "used only once" warning.  I would expect a "print() on unopened filehandle" warning, but maybe it was open, and he just didn't notice the output was in that file.

Comment: @cjm, yes, that was the point of the later ("not going where you think") comment.

Comment: `sd 'line to be removed'$'\n' '' files`. Add `--string-mode` to disable regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're printing to a filehandle which you have not yet defined.  At least you haven't defined it in your sample code.  If you enable strict and warnings, you'll get the following message:

```
Name "main::NEWLIST" used only once: possible typo at remove.pl line 16.

print NEWLIST $LINE unless ($LINE =~ m/$name/);
```

This code should work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 

removeTime( "john" ); 

sub removeTime { 
    my $name = shift; 

    open( FILE, "<times.txt" ); 
    my @LINES = <FILE>; 
    close( FILE ); 
    open( FILE, ">times.txt" ); 
    foreach my $LINE ( @LINES ) { 
        print FILE $LINE unless ( $LINE =~ m/$name/ ); 
    } 
    close( FILE ); 
    print( "Reservation successfully removed.<br/>" ); 
}
```

A couple of other things to note:

1) Your sample code calls removeReservation() when you mean removeTime()

2) You don't require the round brackets in your subroutine definition unless your intention is to use [prototypes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes).  See my example above.

Comment: Thanks for this concept, i was struggling to do read and update line in one file handle!

Answer (score 20):

```
perl -ni -e 'print unless /whatever/' filename
```

Comment: or, conversely:`perl -pi -e 's/.*whatever.*//' filename`

Comment: @r_2 Does that remove the line, or just make it empty? I'd expect the latter behavior.

Comment: It just makes it empty

Comment: `... | sed -i '/^$/d' filepath` to remove empty lines or `... | sed -i '/^\s*$/d' filepath`(including the ones with only spaces). Related: https://serverfault.com/a/252927/345785

Answer (score 8):

Oalder's answer is [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167042/368630), but he should have tested whether the open statements succeeded or not. If the file `times.txt` doesn't exist, your program would continue on its merry way without a word of warning that something terrible has happened.

Same program as oalders' but:

1. Testing the results of the `open`.
2. Using the three part open statement which is more goof proof. If your file name begins with `>` or `|`, your program will fail with the old two part syntax.
3. Not using global file handles -- especially in subroutines. File handles are normally global in scope. Imagine if I had a file handle named `FILE` in my main program, and I was reading it, I called this subroutine. That would cause problems. Use locally scoped file handle names.
4. Variable names should be in lowercase. Constants are all uppercase. It's just a standard that developed over time. Not following it can cause confusion.
5. Since oalders put the program in a subroutine, you should pass the name of your file in the subroutine as well...

Here's the program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 

removeTime( "john", "times.txt" ); 

sub removeTime { 
    my $name      = shift;
    my $time_file = shift;

    if (not defined $time_file) {
        #Make sure that the $time_file was passed in too.
        die qq(Name of Time file not passed to subroutine "removeTime"\n);
    }

    # Read file into an array for processing
    open( my $read_fh, "<", $time_file )
       or die qq(Can't open file "$time_file" for reading: $!\n); 

    my @file_lines = <$read_fh>; 
    close( $read_fh ); 

    # Rewrite file with the line removed
    open( my $write_fh, ">", $time_file )
        or die qq(Can't open file "$time_file" for writing: $!\n);

    foreach my $line ( @file_lines ) { 
        print {$write_fh} $line unless ( $line =~ /$name/ ); 
    } 
    close( $write_fh ); 

    print( "Reservation successfully removed.<br/>" ); 
}
```

Comment: This is stylistically better than my answer.  IIRC I just changed the minimum amount of code to get the example working but the 3 arg open and checking to see if the open succeeded are key if you really want to clean things up.  Using autodie and or File::Slurp could really cut down on the code as well, but this is a far more thorough response than my own.

Answer (score 4):

This is in the [FAQ](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html).

[How do I change, delete, or insert a line in a file, or append to the beginning of a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-change%2c-delete%2c-or-insert-a-line-in-a-file%2c-or-append-to-the-beginning-of-a-file%3f)

It's always worth checking the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone wants to remove all lines from a file.

For example, a file (4th line is empty; 5th line has 3 spaces):

```
t e st1
test2 a
  e

   
aa 
    bb bb
test3a
cc
```

To remove lines which match a pattern some might use:

```sh
# Remove all lines with a character 'a'
perl -pi -e 's/.*a.*//' fileTest && sed -i '/^$/d' fileTest;
```

The result:

```
t e st1
  e
   
    bb bb
cc
```

Related:

```sh
perl -h
    # -p                assume loop like -n but print line also, like sed
    # -i[extension]     edit <> files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
    # -e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)

sed -h
    # -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
    #                edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166932/how-to-remove-one-line-from-a-file-using-perl/10167042#comment87997068_16919572), [Reference 2](https://serverfault.com/a/252927/345785)